# How to convert one type to another when resolving a dependency in castle windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm trying to implement a factory class to help me instantiate a class, `FooBar`.

`FooBar` looks like this:

```
public class BarConsumer
{
    BarConsumer(IEnumerable<Bar>, IWibble wibbles)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

My Factory looks like this:

```
interface IBarConsumerFactory
{
    BarConsumer MakeBarConsumerFromFoo(Foo)
}
```

`IWibble` is satisfied by Castle.Windsor. My `IEnumerable<Bar>` can be derived from a single instance of `Foo`. I have a class, `BarConsumerFactory` that makes a `BarConsumer` from a `Foo`. Unfortunately though, to turn a `Foo` into a `IEnumerable<Bar>`, it needs some dependencies (`IFillangie`). All of those dependencies are registered with Castle.Windsor.

Currently, I have this:

```
interface IBarConsumerTypeFactory
{
    BarConsumer MakeBarConsumer(IEnumerable<Bar> bars)
}

class BarConsumerFactory : IBarConsumerFactory
{
    BarConsumerFactory(
       IFillangie fillangie, 
       IBarConsumerTypeFactory barConsumerTypeFactory)
    {
       ...
    }

    BarConsumer MakeBarConsumerFromFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        //do some processing to create "processedFoo"
        ...

        return _barConsumerTypeFactory.MakeBarConsumer(
            _fillangie.FinalStep(processedFoo));
    }
}
```

so `IBarConsumerTypeFactory` is registered with `AsFactory()`, and matches the constructor directly.

So, this *works*, but is *very* ugly.

Is there any way I can drop the `IBarConsumerTypeFactory`, and simply show Castle.Windsor how to convert a `Foo` into a `IEnumerable<Bar>` using `BarConsumerFactory` (which would then be called `FooBarConverter` I guess?)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can register your custom factory in the following way:

`Component.For<IBarConsumerFactory>().ImplementedBy<BarConsumerFactory>().LifestyleTransient()`

and completely remove the

`Component.For<IBarConsumerFactory>().AsFactory()`

line.

This way consumers can still depend on `IBarConsumerFactory` but Castle Windsor will internally pass them `BarConsumerFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

refact your code about processing Foo into IEnumerable to a facility, and register it with windsor, the doc of facility is here https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/facilities.md

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement your abstract factory like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212457/6695901), you can use a custom `ITypedFactoryComponentSelector`:

```cs
public class BarConsumerFactoryConverter : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    private IFillangie _fillangie;

    public BarConsumerFactoryConverter(IFillangie fillangie)
    {
        _fillangie = fillangie;
    }

    protected override Arguments GetArguments(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        if (arguments == null)
            return null;

        Arguments argumentMap = new Arguments();
        ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();

        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (parameters[i].ParameterType == typeof(Test))
                argumentMap.Add(typeof(IEnumerable<IBar>), _fillangie.FinalStep((Test) arguments[i]));
            else
                argumentMap.Add(parameters[i].Name, arguments[i]);
        }

        return argumentMap;
    }
}
```

This `BarConsumerFactoryConverter` has to be registered with your `IWindsorContainer` as well:

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<BarConsumerFactoryConverter, ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>());
```

Finally you have to tell your factory to use `BarConsumerFactoryConverter` as its component selector:

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<IBarConsumerFactory>().AsFactory(f => f.SelectedWith<BarConsumerFactoryConverter>()));
```